# What table and fields would I require for a friend request system on Spotify

Tags: sql, database, spotify

Require some help on in what table and fields required to create a database on sql.

The aim of the project is to design implement social side of program like Spotify. Requirements as follows

1. If the customer has a paid subscription The customer can add other customers as friends provided the friend is a paying subscriber.
2. The customer can mark themselves as discoverable so that friends can find them or the customer can remain as private.
3. To add someone as a friend a private message is sent to another customer, who can accept or decline.
4. Upon acceptance of a friend invite they are added as a friend to the customer’s ‘friend list’.
5. A customer can remove a friend from their “friends list” at any time.
6. Subscribed users must be able to see the tracks in their friends’ playlists but should not be able to edit them.

I have struggling create the database table and fields and would like some help.

Answer (score 0):

You're gonna need what they call either a lookup table or a bridge table to hold relationships

**Example**

```
create table customer (
customer_id int, 
customer_name varchar(126), 
discoverable_flag smallint,
);

create table customer_relationship (
customer_initiated_id int, 
customer_requested_id int, 
relationship_status varchar(10) 
);
```

I have left the create statements in a pseudo code basis.

I get the feeling I'm doing your homework, so I will let you figure out the rest

Comment: I had a message table but not sure if that was required and what fields were required in it